# Does HttpResponseObject change after read().decode('utf-8') in python openurl method?

Tags: python, python-3.6, httpresponse

I am currently learning python 3 and was playing around with openurl when I noticed that after read().decode('utf-8') the length of my HTTP response object became zero and I cant figure out why is it behaving like that.

```
story = urlopen('http://sixty-north.com/c/t.txt')
print(story.read().decode('utf-8'))
story_words = []
for line in story:
    line_words = line.decode('utf-8').split()
    for word in line_words:
        story_words.append(word)
story.close()
print(story_words)
```

On execution of the print command on line 2, the length of the HTTP response in story changes from 593 to 0 and an empty array is printed on story words. If I remove the print command the story_words array is populated.

```
Output with read().decode()
It was the best of times
it was the worst of times
it was the age of wisdom
it was the age of foolishness
it was the epoch of belief
it was the epoch of incredulity
it was the season of Light
it was the season of Darkness
it was the spring of hope
it was the winter of despair
we had everything before us
we had nothing before us
we were all going direct to Heaven
we were all going direct the other way
in short the period was so far like the present period that some of
its noisiest authorities insisted on its being received for good or for
evil in the superlative degree of comparison only
[]

Output without it - 

['It', 'was', 'the', 'best', 'of', 'times', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'worst', 'of', 'times', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'age', 'of', 'wisdom', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'age', 'of', 'foolishness', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'epoch', 'of', 'belief', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'epoch', 'of', 'incredulity', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'season', 'of', 'Light', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'season', 'of', 'Darkness', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'spring', 'of', 'hope', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'winter', 'of', 'despair', 'we', 'had', 'everything', 'before', 'us', 'we', 'had', 'nothing', 'before', 'us', 'we', 'were', 'all', 'going', 'direct', 'to', 'Heaven', 'we', 'were', 'all', 'going', 'direct', 'the', 'other', 'way', 'in', 'short', 'the', 'period', 'was', 'so', 'far', 'like', 'the', 'present', 'period', 'that', 'some', 'of', 'its', 'noisiest', 'authorities', 'insisted', 'on', 'its', 'being', 'received', 'for', 'good', 'or', 'for', 'evil', 'in', 'the', 'superlative', 'degree', 'of', 'comparison', 'only']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `urlopen` returns a file-like buffer object. With `read` you can get the response up to a number of bytes or get the whole response until `EOF` when not passing a parameter. After reading, the buffer is empty. This means that you need to save the returned value in a variable before printing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I also noticed that, if the read() is commented out then on every iteration the buffers response is consumed until it is empty.